# Getting reCaptcha after enable play integrity api ni flutter release build in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

Getting reCaptcha in phone authentication after enabling play integrity api.

google cloud console project also link with api sha-1 and sha-256 added in firebase project so, need to know that what i missing to enable or need to add any dependency in flutter please suggest so that reCaptcha screen will remove while otp authentication like android device verification api if any one know.

please add better tutorial if any one know, it will better help me to understand.

Thanks in advance.